# Can't find installed software

Tags: macos, install, dmg, pkg

Forgive me if this is a dumb question, but I've tried all sorts of things, and need help.

I needed to use some software from the Internet, so I got some installers for them. All of them are *.dmg* and have *.pkg* installers. I went through the installers and installed them, but after installing them I can't find them anywhere. Could someone please help me find them?

Logs tell me they were installed:

```
Jun 27 15:10:55 myMacBookAir installd[15594]: Installed "u-he TyrellN6" ()
Jun 27 15:24:43 myMacBookAir installd[15594]: Installed "Crystal" ()
Jun 28 11:07:11 myMacBookAir installd[15594]: Installed "Serum" (1.017)
```

When I use Spotlight, all I find are the *.dmg* files. I running OS X El Capitan.

I did look in the Applications folder, they were not there.

Comment: Did you look in Finder under `Applications`?

Comment: I did. Wasn't there :(

Comment: Did you try using Spotlight or Launch Pad? ...Or look for a new folder: ~/Applications?

Comment: Aren't these all audio plugins? What VST or AU compatible audio software are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hitting **Command+L** (which should open the installation log details) while you're running the installer pkg and you should see the installing target path in those logs.

Comment: Thanks :) I found the path and found the things. Strange that spotlight didn't work.